# How to get collection name from forerunnerdb

Tags: javascript, forerunnerdb

Does anyone know how to get the collection name of a forerunnerdb database? I need to lookup what collecion data is in dynamically, but have not seen how to get the name of a collection created to check its name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do db.collections() to get a list of collections currently available.